# php uploader $_FILES undefined

Tags: php

Hello everyone I been trying get php uploader working but having a lot of issues.  Here is my code.  I'm getting Undefined Index errors on the $_FILES.  Am I missing something?  I checked the php.ini for the max file size and a list of other things.  I checked my tmp folder nothing in it.  I was able to use this a little while ago but when I increased my max file upload it seemed like everything broke..

PHP FILE

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = 'Test/';

$target_path = $target_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

printf($_FILES);
print_r($_FILES);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

HTML FILE

```
    <form method="post" action="UploadPHP.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

The Error I'm getting

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in /Movies/UploadPHP.php on line 10 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Movies/UploadPHP.php on line 12 ArrayArray ( ) 
Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in /Movies/UploadPHP.php on line 15 
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
```

So I decided to look at some other stuff and now the server wont accept any posts!  I have no idea what went wrong I changed the post size to : 2048M and restarted apache....  So lost now.

Comment: what's the output of `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: Array Array () is what I'm getting from print_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be getting those errors when the form attempts to submit the file to the script, but there was no file sent to the script.  Make sure you do checking prior for the $_FILES['uploadedfile'] to be set prior to trying to move an uploaded file out of the temp directory.

Your MAX_FILE_SIZE is only set to 100000 bytes, so it's only 97.65625KB, make sure the file you are uploading is less than that size.  Otherwise as I recall, it does not submit the form.

Comment: Ya the test File I was using was a txt file.  I just now started noticing that I can't post ANYTHING to the server.  This must be the root of the issue.  I just don't have any idea why this is happening now the server and php was fine up intill I changed the ini now the posting is all messed up.  I think apache is fine as I can see all my php files its just posting data to those files doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check `"upload_max_filesize"` in `.htaccess`. if the provided file size is greater then specified, then `$_FILES` will not get anyting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a custom framework today where someone had "cleverly" moved `$_FILES` into another class variable and then called `unset($_FILES)`.

Spent awhile tracking that one down, so check for hairballs like that.